# mysql - FLOAT storage size switches from 4 to 8 bytes when the precision is 24 or 25?

Tags: mysql, types, floating-point, pymysql

really a tiny inconsistency, but still - the [mysql 8.0 doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/floating-point-types.html) says that:

> A precision from 0 to 23 results in a 4-byte single-precision FLOAT column. A precision from 24 to 53 results in an 8-byte double-precision DOUBLE column.

I've tested that multiple times using PyMySql `pymysql==0.10.1` on a `MySql 8.0` (provisioned on GCP as Cloud SQL), and I saw that if you specify `FLOAT(24)` (or below) MySql reports a FLOAT, while if you specify `FLOAT(25)` (or above) MySql reports a DOUBLE

Comment: [IEEE "float"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) has 24 bits of binary significance.  Unlcear how mysql rates it.  I'd say " 0 to 23" text appears to be off-by-one.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica - aren't the numbers here *decimal* precision?

Comment: Binary, not decimal.  [`FLOAT(M,D)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/floating-point-types.html) appears to have used decimal precision.